# Handling back button, changing pages in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have "MainPage" and "FriendsPage".How I can simulate the back button if user clicked the back button in "FrinedPage".MaiPage can show only one time.

MainPage>Friendspage, no returning back
.

I think I need to use "OnNavigatedFrom" method, but I don't know how.Please help me.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. If you're on FriendsPage and hit the back button, do you want to skip MainPage and navigate back out of the application?

Comment: In MaiPage I have Webbrowser that no needs to be displayed twice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a button click call

```
NavigationService.GoBack();
```

or, in VB.NET,

```
NavigationService.GoBack()
```

Here is the MSDN docs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.goback.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to handle/Override OnBackKeyPress and set cancel = true to prevent moving backwards in your app.

Comment: I also need to exit from it in Firends.page on Back pressed

Comment: @wsevendays In line with several other peoples comments, I think you are going to have trouble with this. Overriding OnBackKeypress (certainly in WP 7.1) will prevent you returning to the main page and throwing an exception will cause the app to quit, but it is nasty. It doesn't  follow the general usage of the phone.  Many people will become confused and frustrated if they can't return to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike WPF, one is not allowed to drop pages from the backstack in a Windows Phone app. Also there is certification requirement that from the first page of the app (assuming MainPage.xaml), the user should be able to hit "Back" & exit the app. So, please consider carefully what you are trying do.

That said, there are couple of ways:

- Override & eat up OnBackKeyPress: This might lead to a jarring user experience though.
- Override OnNavigatedTo() in MainPage and throw an unhandled exception to exit app or take other appropriate action (NavigationService.GoBack() or some other page). There was a nice post about exiting a SL app ([here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/01/exiting-a-windows-phone-application.aspx)). Also, if using GoBack(), keep in mind that you are now taking over some responsibility to maintain the backstack after the jump; might have to be done consistently throughout the app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @willmel Interesting! I did not know that. Is there any documentation or links?

Comment: Yes, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice_members%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

Comment: I'm super excited about it though. I rolled my own to handle a type of navigation I was using, and it was a little buggy. I'd much rather use one supported by MS :)

Comment: In MaiPage I have Webbrowser that no needs to be displayed twice

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a way to get what you want without violating the requirements.

what is on your "mainpage" that you don't want the user to go back to? 
from your limited info, it sounds like the mainpage shouldn't be your "main" page then.

You probably want your friendspage to be the main page, and have a popup or something that includes whatever you would have had on your "mainpage".

for other non-standard situations, there are *some* exceptions to the navigation rules, see the "nonlinear navigation" stuff: http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/12/13/solving-circular-navigation-in-windows-phone-silverlight-applications.aspx

Comment: In MaiPage I have Webbrowser that no needs to be displayed twice